# img.variable is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor

So `img`is an object and the key is a  name of a function and the value is a function .

```html
     img = { logoUploader: [Function: Uploader],
      homeSliderUploader: [Function: Uploader],
      navLogoUploader: [Function: Uploader],
      homeLogoUploader: [Function: Uploader],
      sideNavLogoUploader: [Function: Uploader],
      AuthLogoUploader: [Function: Uploader],
      AuthBackgroundUploader: [Function: Uploader]
 }
```

And I want to loop through img and grab the key of the object and use it   to call that function by setting it to a var. And when run this code I get a `img.variable is not a constructor` error.

```js
  for (var variable in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(variable)) {
      console.log(variable)
      var uploader = new img.variable()
    }
  }
```

What I dont understand is that when I hardcode var `uploader = new img.logoUploader()` it works perfect so why wont `variable` not work, `variable` in the loop should be logoUploader in the first time through the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `[]` notation here as you are dealing with variable property names.

```
new img[variable]()
```